# How to store image on firebase storage with blob on Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase

From the frontend this could easily be done with the uploadBytes function, but the firebase admin storage package only has an upload method that requires a local URL to an image. How do I send a blob?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your buffer to a temporary file, upload it, and then delete the file. You could do something like this

```
// Write your data to a file
// You might need to pass your data in the form Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(data-here))
fs.writeFileSync('somepath.something', Buffer.from(pass - your - data - here))
// Upload your data
await firebase().storage().bucket().upload('somepath.something')
// Delete the temporary file (crucial)
fs.unlinkSync('somepath.something')
```

If your file is massive, you might need to increase your functions allocated memory as the temporary file will be written to a directory called 'tmp/whatever-you-call-it', and this is stored in memory.